# error with upload images in Attachments using Croogo and cakephp

Tags: image, cakephp, upload, attachment, croogo

Hope someone can help me!

I'm trying to upload an image in Attachments and insert image in a page using croogo.

And when I upload i keep getting the same error message:

Security Error
The requested address was not found on this server.
Request blackholed due to "auth" violation.

The images are saved in the uploads folder but i cant get them to display on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some line of code in your controller

```
public function afterFilter() {
        if (($this->request->isPost() || $this->request->isPut()) && empty($_POST) && empty($_FILES)) {
            $this->Security->csrfCheck = false;
        }
    }
```

*OR*
May be you forgot to define multipart in your form.

```
echo $this->Form->create('Something', array( 'type' => 'file'));
```

Hope this help you.